# Creating a merge conflict after pull request

Tags: git

I am currently learning github and git which seems so much difficult to me. Right now I have read about Merge Conflicts and I would really like to see it working. But I don't know how to create it.

I have a repo published [here](https://github.com/tyagivipul629/React-Coursera.git).It is synced with my local repo. It has a file README.md which has the content `This is My Coursera React Project Vipul Tyagi`.

What I am looking for is When I change README.md and pull this repo on my local machine, I should see the four options in README file(Accept incoming change, Accept current change, Accept Both changes, Compare Changes). I checked out [this](https://jonathanmh.com/how-to-create-a-git-merge-conflict/) resource, but it doesn't have a pull request, which I want.

Please tell me the way to achieve this thing.

Thank You.

Comment: Why the downvote? I think I explained my problem very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what I am really looking for is that I should see the options "Accept Current Changes" and "Accept Incoming Changes" when I pull remote repo to my local machine.
>
> A while ago I was working on a project whose code was continuouslyy being pushed to github and each time I used to pull the code from remote, I would get a merge conflict in some files.
>
> Why did I see those two options in the project I mentioned?

Because you had committed local modification that were not pushed.
And then you pulled modifications from the remote for the same file. That triggered a conflict.

But for your own repository, where you are the only one working on it, and pushing to it, a pull is likely to *not* trigger any conflict, which will explain the lack of "Accept Current Changes" and "Accept Incoming Changes".

Comment: I made a branch named ``merger`` on github and changed the same line on README.md. I then committed the change to ``merger`` and then merged it with master( Without any conflicts). However, When I pulled the master branch on my local repo, then I suddenly saw those four options in README.md. Even though I deleted merger branch, then why these four options appeared then? How do you explain this?

Comment: @VIPULTYAGI Because you had a local commit on master for that file, commit which was not pushed.

Comment: ``Because you had committed local modification that were not pushed.
And then you pulled modifications from the remote for the same file. That triggered a conflict.`` I'm doing same over here

Comment: It looks like I need to reborn to understand git completely. It is the most difficult thing I have came across in my life.

Comment: @VIPULTYAGI https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts is a good start. I like https://learngitbranching.js.org/ too.